# Tensorflow: different fetches bring different results

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am playing around with `Tensorflow` and there is one thing I can't seem to understand: the role of the `fetches` argument for the `Session.run()`.
From the [doc](http://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud730/lessons/6370362152/concepts/71191606550923#):

> To fetch the outputs of operations, execute the graph with a run()
>   call on the Session object and pass in the tensors to retrieve.

What I understood is that the parameter is used to read certain values from the from the run step. I see, though, that different `fetches` bring to different results

```
....´
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(preactivations_output, tf_train_labels))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
...
train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(preactivations_output)
...
# This produces a model with 89% accuracy
_, l, predictions = session.run(
  [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
# This produces a model with 10% accuracy
l, predictions = session.run(
  [loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

So now I wonder what else the `fetches` parameter is used for, given that it seems to influence the way the training is run. I didn't really understand it from the documentation...

Comment: `[optimizer, loss, train_prediction]` will update the parameters with a single optimization step

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov you mean that the fetches parameters also indicates which parameter of the graph have to be updated during the step?

Comment: That is correct, a fetch can have side effects

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov . If you put it as an answer I will accept it